# How to send a mail from gitlab after any activity?

Tags: push-notification, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

We are using gitlab for CI/CD. my colleagues need pipeline, merge request, commit related status. How should I receive the mails from them and how did they receive my activity through mails? We are using outlook and google account. If we use SMTP? How should I deploy that? by giving everyone's mail.

Comment: You should really clarify your question. At least I don't understand what `How should I receive the mails from them` means, or what is `how did they receive my activity through mails`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience , What I'm trying to say means how did I integrate my colleagues(6 members) mail id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using self-managed or SaaS? If the first one, start with configuring [SMTP settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html)

Then, read [email notifications documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html)

If you use SaaS (gitlab.com), only the second one will be relevant to you.

If this does not help, please ask more specific question (explaining what you try, what didn't work) after you read these docs.

Comment: We are using gitlab SaaS, yes I know to integrate the mail in notification setting in gitlab, is there any other option or this is enough?

Comment: "If you use SaaS (gitlab.com), only the second one will be relevant to you."- What is the second one?

Comment: Second link - email notifications documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always create an MS teams team with yourself and the people who need to be notified, irrespective of if they are gitlab users. Take the mail id of that team and add it to your gitlab profile, and for this project, use custom notification and use that email id for the specific events. Everyone involved will get the mails.

If you are using google accounts, create a google group and use the group email id.