Sending release notes automatically to users when tag release
Is there an easy automation solution for GitLab to send release notes to defined user list, when tag release is ready? I know I can write a script for that as a separate job, however first would like to try other means.
Release notes are part of tag already.

I'm unaware of such a feature, but I found this question about sending mails from a pipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703155/how-to-send-an-email-from-gitlab-ci-pipelines-job

GitLab provides an RSS feed for any repos releases:

You can pair this with Apps like Feed-Notifier to receive real-time notifications on almost any platform.
